Show $C_b\left(\Omega\right)$ is closed w.r.t. pointwise multiplication.
If $\Omega$ is a topological space, then I want to show the set $C_b\left(\Omega\right)$ of continuous, bounded, complex-valued functions on $\Omega$ is closed with respect to
$$\begin{align}
C_b\left(\Omega\right)^2&\to C_b\left(\Omega\right),\\
\left(f,g\right)&\mapsto fg,
\end{align}$$
where $\left(fg\right)\left(\omega\right)=f\left(\omega\right)g\left(\omega\right)$.
In particular, I want to show $fg$ is continuous.
To this end, my approach is to fix $f,g\in C_b\left(\Omega\right)$, define
$$\begin{align}
\mu:\Omega&\to\mathbb C^2,\\
\omega&\mapsto\left(f\left(\omega\right),g\left(\omega\right)\right),
\end{align}$$
show $\mu$ is continuous, and use the fact that
$$\begin{align}
\nabla:\mathbb C^2&\to\mathbb C,\\
(x,y)&\mapsto xy
\end{align}$$
is continuous to conclude $fg=\nabla\circ\mu$ is continuous since it is a composition of continuous functions.
Is this approach sound? Is there a simpler one?

Your approach is fine. I don't think there is an approach which is simpler than what you have here to show continuity of $fg$. As for other options, one is to show that for each $x_{0}\in \Omega$ and $\varepsilon > 0$ that there is some open neighbourhood $U$ of $x_{0}$ such that $x\in U$ implies $|(fg)(x) - (fg)(x_{0})| < \varepsilon$. Another option is to use nets, although this approach also makes use of the continuity of multiplication of complex numbers.
